# Does Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth change anything if there are no corrupt files?

Tags: windows, windows-10, restore, repair, dism

I ran RestoreHealth instead of ScanHealth-CheckHealth accidentally and now it's taking a while to complete and i think stopping it now could cause some issues.
Will this change anything in my windows?

Note from comments

> I just wanted to check for corrupt files using ScanHealth and then decide if i want to restore them using RestoreHealth. But instead i ran RestoreHealth without checking if anything is corrupt.

Comment: It's supposed to take awhile.  Can you provide the relevant information from the log that has been generated so far?  You should allow the operation to finish.

Comment: https://controlc.com/dca68805 password is windows

Comment: The log was recently updated at 16:03 which was 26 minutes ago.

Comment: I ran the command on a different computer.

Comment: Then while browsing my own computer i found out that i ran the incorrect command and posted here than went to check with the computer if it finished.

Comment: Did you notice anything changing in the log?

Comment: You didn't run a command that would change anything on your system necessarily.  What was the incorrect command you did run?  Instead of submitting another comment, that is temporary, you should edit your question.

Comment: What i meant is that i just wanted to check for corrupt files using ScanHealth and then decide if i want to restore them using RestoreHealth. But instead i ran RestoreHealth without checking if anything is corrupt.